# Rails updating DB constantly (external values)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to ask if there is any way how to update database from external source to my **Rails DB** constantly (every 1 hour)...

I was trying to do that but when i do that my DB is duplicated + added new files so is there any `if` statement where can i just add new values?

- I'm pulling DB (JSON) from BitBucket(commits)
- Then i'm saving that into my Rails DB and returning in view.
- I tried for that use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

**bitbucket.rb**

```
class Bitbucket < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.savedata
    require 'bitbucket_rest_api'   
    bitbucket = BitBucket.new login:'...', password:'...'
    repo = bitbucket.repos.commits.list '...', '...'
    repo["values"].each do |r|
      create(
        name: r["author"]["user"]["display_name"],
        message: r["message"],
        date: r["date"]
      )
    end
  end
end
```

I have to run first in Rails console **`Bitbucket.connection`** then **`Bitbucket.savedata`** to save into DB.

Thanks for any advice and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, If I understand it right you want to pull data from bitbucket every 1 hour, and update your database only with new 'values'. In that case the question how to know if you have an entry in the database already or not is up to you.

For instance you could ask:

```
author_name = r["author"]["user"]["display_name"]
message = r["message"]
date = r["date"]

unless exists?(name: author_name, message: message, date: date)
  create(name: author_name, message: message, data: date)
end
```

Doku for 'exists?': 
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class

Alternatively you could use 'first_or_create':

http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create

Comment: Nice one! Really appreciate it.. Code updated, so i gonna create a new commit and test it..